# How to customise drupal 7 user registration, login, password reset form

Tags: php, drupal-7

How to customise drupal 7 user registration, login, password. Further I need to add some extra fields to the registration and how to do the field validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add extra fields to registration form here.

```
admin/config/people/accounts/fields
Configuration => People => Account settings => Manage fields
```

Comment: Can u please suggest about country field. I want to add a country and state field and state field should be dependent on country field. Also suggest about customizing forms.

Comment: Try this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/addressfield
Go through the module description first.

The field configuration lets you determine which elements of an address should be present in the field widget form and which ones should be rendered for display.

For customizing the templates for user login, register and password - follow this: https://www.loginradius.com/engineering/customize-user-login-register-and-forgot-password-page-in-drupal-7/

Comment: Can we use webforms for user registration and login. As I want if a user logged in then he will be redirected to his personal area. If yes then please suggest examples how to use webforms.